# Angular HttpClient can't get response body message

Tags: angular, post, httpclient

I am planning using [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) post to my getFeedback endpoint and get response and show it in my app. 
I have one codeService and one dashboard component, This is the code for post in my code service:

```
     //method 1
 async generateFeedbackPost() {
        var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        var body = new URLSearchParams();
        body.set('code', this.code);
        return this.http.post(this.url, body.toString(), { headers }).toPromise();
    }
    //method 2
generateFeedbackPost2() {
    var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    var body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('code', this.code);
    return this.http.post(url, body.toString(), {headers});
}
```

In my dashboard component I call these methods:

```
this.codeService.generateFeedbackPost2().subscribe(data => {console.log(data);});
this.codeService.generateFeedbackPost().then(data => {console.log(data);});
```

I have tried these two ways, however, both of them print null in console. however, in my chrome developer tools network tab, I can exactly see the results:

[image]

Do you know how to retrieve these messages back?

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`?

Comment: both returns null

Comment: It could be a cors error. Please check if the domain names of the website you are using and the api are the same.

Comment: did u want to use url like `/xxx?code=yyy`

Comment: Thanks guys, I have fixed it. The I forget to change my response to json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error, so you cannot see the `data` which will be shown in the case the request was successful.

In order to see the result, error in this case, you can use this:

```
this.codeService.generateFeedbackPost2().subscribe(
    data => {console.log(data);},
    error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: I have figure it out, I have made one mistake: in my web service part, I forgot to change the result to json, I just directly return string. Your JSON.stringfy reminds me that. After I have fix that part, two methods both works!! I tried add this error part and it do print out some useful messages too said json can't parse the string. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JudahFlynn I'm happy it helped.